# Issues with Many-to-Many relationship in AWS Graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

We have a many-to-many relationship between cities and benefits. Many cities can be assigned to one benefit and many benefits can be assigned to one city.

We have the following schema:

```
type City @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    benefits: [CityBenefit] @connection(name: "cityBenefit")
}
type Benefit @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    category: [Category] @connection
    company: String!
    description: String!
    website: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    address: String
    global: Boolean!
    cities: [CityBenefit] @connection(name: "benefitCity")
}
type Category @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}
type CityBenefit @model {
    id: ID!
    city: City @connection(name: "cityBenefit")
    benefit: Benefit @connection(name: "benefitCity")
}
```

After adding a city and a benefit, we can’t get this information in and out. the city in CityBenefit is null and same for benefit.

With this model, it's still not possible to filter for all benefits in a given city.

can you please help us? What is missing or wrong exactly?

Comment: What was your query?

Comment: I am actually struggling to find the syntax for an appsync query to for example : list all benefits for a cit, can you help please ?@yunzen

Comment: As yunzen asked, can you share you query and resolvers? Also, you might find this link to help, an AppSync engineer explained a workaround to doing many to many. It's also serving as a tracking feature request for first class support of it: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/91